# Azure database for postgresql hyperscale with VPN gateway

Tags: azure, security, networking

I cannot find any information on this in the Azure documentation so please forgive me if i've missed this.

We want to use the Azure hyperscale database for an upcoming project but one of the things we want to do is put a VPN gateway in front of the database and allow people to connect to it over that VPN.
I can't find any information on whether or not the hyperscale databases support the use of private links for example which would allow us to NAT to an internal address from a VPN gateway subnet.

Has anyone tried to do this and could suggest whether or not it's possible to address a hyperscale Azure database of postgresql on an internal IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently, it's not possible to use private links for that because

> the Private Link allows you to create private endpoints for Azure
> Database for PostgreSQL - **Single server**
>
> The private link feature is only available for Azure Database for
> PostgreSQL servers in the **General Purpose or Memory Optimized pricing
> tiers**. Ensure the database server is in one of these pricing tiers.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-data-access-and-security-private-link and https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/postgresql/hyperscale-citus/

Comment: Thanks Nancy! Not the end of the world for our use case but thank you for getting back to me on this really appreciated